# How to model price modifiers?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-attribute-value

How do I model the price of products that may or may not have price modifiers. For example, say I have a t-shirt for sale that has different sizes and different colors:

- Small, White = $10
- Small, Black = $10
- Large, White = $15
- Large, Black = $20

Keep in mind, that not all price modifiers are going to be "size" and "color". Also, some products may not have price modifiers at all. How should this information be modeled in the database?

My gut feeling is to go with EAV, but I am always worried whenever I start thinking EAV. The way I would model this using EAV would

```
products
 - id
 - name

prices
- id
- product_id
- attribute
- value
```

And I would always have attribute = "amount" and value = whatever the price is.

**I am concerned that this is not the correct way to model such data. Suggestions/feedback?**

Answer (score 0):

as you know in most of manufacturing and especially costing systems you'll see different modelling and difficulties for such these data, if now you have access to any famous ERP systems you can see their architecture, but as my own Idea the attribute you mentioned is great.

this allow you to have and manage all products, attributes and product attributes easilly:

```
products
 - id
 - name

attributes
 - id
 - attribute_id
 - attribute_name
 - attribute_type

product_attribute_values
 - id
 - product_id
 - attribute_id
 - value
```

now we have problem with pricing for products with multiple attributes, the thing I think is to specify how much attributes have role in pricing (i.e. let's say two) then we need something like this:

```
product_attribute_price
 - id
 - product_attribute_values_id_1
 - product_attribute_values_id_2
 - price
```

as I told most of ERP systems has great architecture for such these scenario but I bring my own thought without copying any of them, and the idea surely may have problems and need more review